# (Yii2) Object of class Object of class app\models\EntryForm could not be converted to string when using shell command

Tags: php, shell, yii2

So i really new to yii2, and want to run shell command that refers to perl command.

This is the code on the Site Controller:

```
public function actionEntry(){
    $model = new EntryForm();

    if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        // $out = shell_exec("../tagger/tag.sh -raw '$model'");
        $out = shell_exec(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/tagger/tag.sh -raw'.$model);
        // print $model;
        return $this->render('entry-confirm', ['model'=>$out]);
        // return $this->render('entry-confirm', ['model'=>$model]);

    } else {
        return $this->render('entry', ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

This is the EntryForm.php that i use to input the text from

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

class EntryForm extends Model
{
    public $Text;

    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['Text'], 'required'],
            ['Text', 'string']
        ];
    }
}
?>
```

This is the view (entry.php)

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin();?>
    <?= $form->field($model,  'Text')->textarea(['rows'=>'4']) ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end();?>
```

and this is the result page (entry-confirm.php)

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
?>

<p>You have entered the following information:</p>

<ul>
    <li><label>Text</label>: <?=Html::encode($model->Text)?></li>
</ul>
```

Now this is the shell command and the expected result to get from it:

```
$ ./tag.sh -raw "Coba dulu ya."
```

Results

> Coba    VB
>   dulu    X
>   ya      X
>   .       Z

Now when i run it inside yii2, i got error like this[image: Error Image]

At which line/ file did i go wrong here? And how do i resolved it? Any help will be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Hav you tried debugging your code? `shell_exec(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/tagger/tag.sh -raw'.$model);` will obviously fail if `$model` is an object without a `__toString()` method, as the error message told you

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your model to a string in the shell_exec which results in an error because your model can't be converted to string. So you can either add a __toString() Method to your model or just add the attribute of your model to the string given to shell_exec.

```php
$out = shell_exec(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/tagger/tag.sh -raw "' . $model->Text . '"');
```

I would also pass `$model->Text` through a function that escapes quotes (") to ensure the content of your Text attribute can't destroy the command given to shell_exec, maybe `addslahes()`.

**EDIT:**
Seems like `escapeshellarg` is better:

```php
$out = shell_exec(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/tagger/tag.sh -raw ' . escapeshellarg($model->Text));
```

Comment: Now the error said: "Trying to get property of 'Text' of non-object at the entry-confirm

Comment: I think the error is now in your entry-confirm view, try changing it to `<?=Html::encode($model) ?>`